# Syntax for making objects callable in python

Tags: python, pytorch

I understand that in python user-defined objects can be made callable by defining a `__call__()` method in the class definition. For example,

```
class MyClass:
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def __call__(self, input1):
    self.my_function(input1)

  def my_function(self, input1):
    print(f"MyClass - print {input1}")

my_obj = MyClass()
# same as calling my_obj.my_function("haha")
my_obj("haha") # prints "MyClass - print haha"
```

I was looking at how `pytorch` makes the `forward()` method of a `nn.Module` object be called implicitly when the object is called and saw some syntax I didn't understand.

In [the line](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/1c5a8125798392f8d7c57e88735f43a14ae0beca/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L1156) that supposedly defines the `__call__` method the syntax used is,

```
__call__ : Callable[..., Any] = _call_impl
```

This seemed like a combination of an annotation (keyword `Callable[` following `:` ignored by python) and a value of `_call_impl` which we want to be called when `__call__` is invoked, and my guess is that this is a shorthand for,

```
def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
```

but wanted to understand clearly how this method of defining functions worked.

My question is: When would we want to use such a definition of callable attributes of a class instead of the usual `def myfunc(self, *args, **kwargs)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Functions are normal first-class objects in python. The name to with which you define a function object, e.g. with a `def` statement, is not set in stone, any more than it would be for an `int` or `list`. Just as you can do

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a
```

to access the elements of `a` through the name `b`, you can do the same with functions. In your first example, you could replace

```
def __call__(self, input1):
    self.my_function(input1)
```

with the much simpler

```
__call__ = my_function
```

You would need to put this line after the definition of `my_function`.

The key differences between the two implementations is that `def __call__(...` creates a new function. `__call__ = ...` simply binds the name `__call__` to the same object as `my_function`. The noticeable difference is that if you do `__call__.__name__`, the first version will show `__call__`, while the second will show `my_function`, since that's what gets assigned by a `def` statement.